# Out Of office Chatter Notification

Tags: chatter, flow, process-builder

I had a requirement where I had to Post Out Of Office Message,whenever an User is on leave. this 
[link](https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/out-of-office-notification-for-chatter-post/) worked good for me.

So when when we post the USER NAME in `FeedItem` then we will get auto meesage in `FeedComment`.

But my requirement is, when we post user name in `FeedComment`, we will get OOO message in next `FeedCommnet`.

**The Soloutions I had :**

1) Create a `Process Builder` for `FeedComment` and follow the same process as described in the post. But, it seems `Process builder` doesn't support `FeedComment` SObject.So, can't proceed with this.

2) Write a `Trigger` on `FeedComment` (`before insert, before Update`), and `insert` accordingly. This solution kind of working, but not as expected. We have to Refresh the page, in order to get new Comment and latest Comment isn't in proper order.

any other solution?

Comment: Is there a specific part of the blog post that isn't working? A specific question that you have?

Comment: @RyanGuest : I updated my question.